# Django error: The Items could not be created because the data didn't validate

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, formset

I get the following error:
**ValueError at /create-items/
The Items could not be created because the data didn't validate.**, and can't find out what the issue is...

Views.py

```
def createMulitpleItemsPage(request):
    currency = '€'

    ItemFormSet = modelformset_factory(Items, form=CreateItemFormset, extra=1)
    qs = Items.objects.none()
    user = request.user.profile
    formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=qs, form_kwargs={'user': user})

    # Create multiple items
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user.profile
        ItemFormSet = modelformset_factory(Items, form=CreateItemFormset, extra=1)
        qs = Items.objects.none()
        formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=qs, form_kwargs={'user': user})

    context = {'formset': formset}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('printing POST: ', request.POST)
        print('printing Errors: ', formset.errors)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset = CreateItemFormset(user=request.user.profile, data=request.POST)
            parent = formset.save(commit=False)
            parent = formset.save()
            for form in formset:
                newitems = form.save(commit=False)
                newitems.user = request.user.profile
                newitems.save()
            return redirect('items')

    return render(request, 'base/mass_create_items.html', context)
```

Forms.py

```
class CreateItemFormset(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateItemFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = Categories.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.fields['item_category'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=qs)

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ['item_name', 'item_category', 'item_start_date', 'item_end_date', 'item_purchase_price', 'item_rest_value']
```

Models.py

```
class Items(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    item_category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    item_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=False)
    item_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=False)
    item_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    item_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    item_purchase_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
    item_rest_value = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    item_saving_goal = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    item_date_delta = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    item_days_passed = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    item_currently_saved = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    item_percentage_saved = models.FloatField(default=0.01, null=True, blank=False)
    item_monthly_saving = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.item_saving_goal = self.item_purchase_price - self.item_rest_value
        self.item_date_delta = (self.item_end_date.year - self.item_start_date.year) * 12 + ( self.item_end_date.month - self.item_start_date.month )
        self.item_days_passed = (date.today().year - self.item_start_date.year) * 12 + ( date.today().month - self.item_start_date.month )
        self.item_currently_saved = self.item_saving_goal * (self.item_days_passed / self.item_date_delta )
        self.item_percentage_saved = self.item_currently_saved / self.item_saving_goal * 100
        self.item_monthly_saving = self.item_saving_goal / self.item_date_delta
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Error looks like this:

> Internal Server Error: /create-items/
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
> line 21, in _wrapped_view
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/jelledekker/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Django/Aurelian web/base/views.py", line
> 304, in createMulitpleItemsPage
> parent = formset.save(commit=False)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/models.py",
> line 458, in save
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: The Items could not be created because the data didn't validate.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the formset for validity before binding it to POST!

```
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset = CreateItemFormset(user=request.user.profile, data=request.POST)
```

Think those two lines need to be reversed.